# How to install Minecraft full version with Python support on a Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian, python, minecraft

After getting a new Pi 4 and launching Minecraft Pi Edition, I have to say it's extremely limited, lacking most of the features that make MC fun. Granted it's abandonware that never made it past alpha, but even so...

What I would like to do is get a full version of Minecraft Java Edition working in Raspbian - modded with support for Python commands. It doesn't have to be a recent version of MC, but at least some monsters, night/day cycles, redstone, TNT that actually explodes, and some freaking sound! ...would be  nice.

The goodness of the full game - but with Python so that it can be educational too.

Web search results indicate such modding for Python support is a thing, but I have not found enough information on how to set it up on the Pi.

(I have a license for the Java Edition that I can probably dig up.)

### Edit: Here is what I know (and don't know) so far:

[Minecraft 1.14.4 can be installed on a Pi 4 if running Gentoo](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cKOxh3fUE4M)

No idea what other versions might work with this method.

No idea if older versions might work using a similar installation method on Raspbian instead of Gentoo.

There is a mod management tool on MC Java Edition called Forge and there is a performance enhancing mod called Optifine. [Some people have reported that with Forge there is no sound](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=239592), but I don't know if that will be true for everyone. In the Gentoo video sound was working... so that just raises more questions.

[Here is a video that talks about Optifine](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=joWPftcK7hs). Just to get an idea of what Optifine is. (No Pi-specific info here.)

I read somewhere that after a certain version of Minecraft a 64-bit OS is required - I think after 1.12(?) So my understanding is that since the current version of Raspbian (Buster) is 32-bit, that prevents any newer versions of MC from being installable on Raspbian. And this is probably why people are using Gentoo. Although if it is possible to use Raspbian it would be nice to be able to stick to one OS instead of dual-booting... because then we're off on another tangent trying to figure out how to set that all up. But if Gentoo (GenPi I guess it would be) is the only way, I will try it.

I also read that Forge works on really early versions of MC too, so at least that's good.

The way to add Python support to MC Java Edition is by adding the [Raspberry Jam Mod](https://www.instructables.com/id/Python-coding-for-Minecraft/). This is done through Forge. [Here is a fairly straightforward video tutorial in Japanese for how to get Raspberry Jam installed if you're on macOS](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ftm47zDzS1c). But I am trying to do this on a Pi 4, so yeah...

This is turning into a bit of a ramble, but I hope the details I've provided will clarify where I am stuck - since I've already received a "what have you tried?" comment.

Comment: MC 1.12.2 https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243946

Comment: MC 1.14.4 https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=260357

Comment: @CoderMike Thank you. No mention of Python in either of those threads. Is it safe to assume Forge and [Raspberry Jam](https://www.instructables.com/id/Python-coding-for-Minecraft/) will work with those configurations?

Comment: The Minecraft-PE version in Raspbian was launched in 2012 and discontinued by Mojang/Microsoft in 2013. Nothing will ever change with it. It's only supplied by the RPF folks in the Raspbian build while it still works (because the python interface is useful).

Comment: @Dougie I am aware of the limitations with the Pi Edition. Microsoft killed it (thanks a lot, jerks!) That's why I am now trying to get the Java Edition running on a Pi 4, and then mod it to take Python commands - the purpose of this question.